# Ядро сайта - что это такое и как его спланировать?

Tags: веб-программирование, архитектура

Очень часто я сталкиваюсь с таким понятием как ядро сайта и в связи с этим постоянно возникает ощущение, что я чего-то не знаю, что-то упустил... В общем возникает "сферический вакуум"... Объясните мне популярно, что значит это понятие? Какие функции он несет и из чего он состоит?

Например: сейчас я пишу свой сайт, где есть и алгоритм подсчета рейтинга, есть модуль добавления статей, регистрация, распределение ролей пользователей и т.д. и т.п... это может называтся "ядром" или нет? Что такое "ядро" сайта и каково его строение?

Answer (score 2):

ядро сайта нужно для того, чтобы связать все эти компоненты(модули) воедино, т.е. подружить их друг с другом. как-то так

Answer (score 1):

У нас ядром считается набор подсистем, абстрагированных от бизнес-логики конкретных приложений, используемый в каждом проекте. У нас ядро состоит из:

- ORM с трёхзвенным linq-провайдером
- Механизма мягкой работы с базой данных (я описывал её в своём ответе на вопрос "Инкрементальный деплой баз данных")
- Различных компонент для автоматической генерации пользовательского интерфейса по объектной модели
- Компонент, обслуживающих сервис-ориентированную архитектуру
- Механизма описания баз данных через xml-файлы. Описания используются как при генерации пользовательского интерфейса, так и при генерации документации по базе.

Разработка приложений у нас выглядит примерно так: создаём новую схему базы данных, импортируем в неё наши стандартные модули и их описания. Генерируем базу данных. Создаём в этой базе данных средствами SQL Server новые объекты для новых модулей, разрабатываемых для конкретного заказчика. Генерируем схему базы данных с новыми модулями. Описываем новые модули и генерируем по ним код бизнс-объектов. Потом расширяем сгенерированную объектную модель бизнес-логикой и специальными методами / свойствами, которые должны отображаться как элементы пользовательского интерфейса. Потом разрабатываем нестандартную функциональность, которую невозможно сгенерировать по объектной модели автоматически. Потом тестируем. Автоматические тесты ловят типичные ошибки проектирования базы данных, настроек кодогенератора и описаний, ручное тестирование позволяет отследить работоспособность программ с точки зрения конечного пользователя.

В общем случае - ядро - это некая инфраструктура, в которую уже вписана прикладная часть приложения. Его имеет смысл делать, если у Вас много похожих проектов, чтобы автоматизировать однотипную работу.

Answer (score 0):

Риторическим духом пахнет.

Думаю, что конкретно каждый вкладывает в это понятие разные вещи.
Но в любом случае, любое ПО это есть набор из функций "получения", "обработки" и "отображения" данных. Соответственно функционал, реализующий это и будет называться ядром, как мне кажется.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю как кто пишет, но у меня обычно веб-приложение - слоёный пирог. Уровень доступа к данным, уровень бизнес-логики и уровень интерфейса. Если нормально написано, то каждый из уровней можно заменить без последствий для остальных. Так что мне кажется у хорошего сайта ядра быть не должно, как-то так

Answer (score 0):

В двух словах ядро это основа приложения , корень дерева